# Does the Subclass constructor inherit variables from the Superclass constructor?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, subclass, private

Given:

```
public class Counter {

   private int count;

   public Counter() {
      count = 5;
   }

   public void increment() {
      count++;
   }

   public void reset() {
      count = 0;
   }

   public int value() {
     return count;
   }
}
```

If I have a subclass with a defined function (not implicitly created), does the subclass constructor inherit the instance variable `count` from the superclass constructor? I ask this because I'm running into a bit of a confusion with regards to `private count`.

```
public class ModNCounter extends Counter {

  int modCount;

  public ModNCounter(int n) {
    modCount = n;
  }

  @Override
  public int value() {
    return super.value() % modCount;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ModNCounter modCounter = new ModNCounter(3);
    System.out.println(modCounter.value()); //prints out 5 % 3 = 2
    modCounter.increment(); // count = 6
    System.out.println(modCounter.value()); //prints out 6 % 3 = 0
    modCounter.reset(); // count = 0
    modCounter.increment(); // count = 1
    System.out.println(modCounter.value()); //print 1 % 3 = 1
  }
}
```

Does the object `modCounter` have a `count` variable? If not, why is `modCounter.increment()` not giving me an error?

Comment: Yes and no.  `count` is there, but because it's private you don't have direct access to it.  You do have access to the publicly declared methods.  This is pretty standard class inheritance.

Comment: According to the tutorial, `private` members (fields and methods) are not said to be inherited by their sub-classes.  They are "there" but a subclass cannot access them, so they're not there-there.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 2):

An inherited class has all the members of its superclass, although they may not be directly accessible to it (if they are `private`). In this case - yes, an instance of `ModNCount` has a `count` member. It cannot access it since it's private, but, as you've seen, it can affect its value using the `increment` and `reset` methods.